# If $x$ is a positive integer, then show that $7x^4 +4x^2 +x+3$ cannot be a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So, I am trying to solve the following problem without modular arithmetic method.

The problem is-

> If $x$ is a positive integer, then show that $7x^4 +4x^2 +x+3$ cannot be a perfect square.

My attempt:
If $7x^4 +4x^2 +x+3$ is a perfect square, it can be expressed as $(ax^2+bx+c)^2$
$(ax^2+bx+c)^2=7x^4 +4x^2 +x+3.$

But, I don't know how to proceed from here.
Any help would be highly appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: "*My attempt...*" $\;-\;$ The polynomial does not have to be the square of another polynomial in order for one of its values at an integer point to be the square of another integer. Take for example $\,p(x)=x^2+5\,$ which is not a perfect square as a polynomial, yet $\,p(2)=9=3^2\,$.

Comment: For a start, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391493/let-x-be-a-positive-integer-show-that-if-x-is-a-perfect-square-then-then), solving the case $x\equiv 0,1\bmod 4$.

Comment: Note that if $x \equiv 2\pmod{4}$, then $x^2$  can not be an odd number.  Consider the trailing $\cdots +3$ term, in this case.

Comment: Is there any other method other than taking modulo 4?

Comment: This is the best method here. Why would you like to avoid this?

Answer (score -1):

Let $7x^4 + 4x^2 + x + 3 = y^2$

All timesed by $7$: $49x^4 + 28x^2 + 7x + 21 = 7y^2$

$(7x^2)^2 + 4(7x^2) + 7x + 21 - 7y^2 = 0$

$(7x^2)^2 + 4(7x^2) + 7(x + 3 - y^2) = 0$

$(7x^2) = [-4 +- \sqrt(4^2 - 28(x + 3 - y^2))]/2$

$(7x^2) = -2 + \sqrt(4 - 7(x + 3 - y^2))]$

i.e. $7y^2 - 7x - 17$ must equal a square

But $7y^2 = 49x^4 + 28x^2 + 7x + 21$, so:

$(49x^4 + 28x^2 + 7x + 21) - 7x - 17 = 49x^4 + 28x^2 + 4$

Assume $49x^4 + 28x^2 + 4 = z^2$

i.e. $(7x^2)^2 + 4(7x^2) + (4 - z^2) = 0$

$(7x^2) = [-4 + \sqrt(4^2 + 4(4 - z^2))]/2$

i.e. $(7x^2) = -2 + \sqrt(4 + 4 - z^2)$

$(7x^2 + 2)^2 = 8 - z^2$

So the only integer value possible for which the RHS is a square is $z = 2$, giving $4$

and implying $7x^2 + 2 = +- 2$ which is not possible in integers.